# Init wrongly taken as an argument

Tags: haskell

```
isPalindrome :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
isPalindrome [] = True
isPalindrome [a] = True
isPalindrome (x:xs) = (x == last xs)  && (isPalindrome init xs)
```

returns me

```
Couldn't match expected type `[a0]' with actual type `[a1] -> [a1]'
In the first argument of `isPalindrome', namely `init'
In the second argument of `(&&)', namely `(isPalindrome init xs)'
In the expression: (x == last xs) && (isPalindrome init xs)
```

I don't understand why Haskell thinks that the argument of isPalindrome is init while it is init xs

Comment: Function application is left-associative, meaning it evaluates from left-to-right. `isPalindrome init xs` is the same as `(isPalindrome init) xs` - you want it the other way around, which means you need extra parenthesis: `isPalindrome (init xs)`.

Comment: works, thanks a lot Xeo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Haskell, the invisible function application operator associates to the left, so `isPalindrome init xs` is interpreted as `(isPalindrome init) xs`. It's done this way because it allows us to use [currying](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Currying) to handle functions with multiple arguments.

To pass `init xs` as one argument, you simply have to use parentheses:

```
isPalindrome (init xs)
```

Comment: A dollar would also do it: `isPalindrome $ init xs`

Comment: Donate a dollar to that expression.